# How to prevent a pop-up dialog-box from changing its position?

Tags: c++, qt

In my application, I have a push-button labeled `Insert` that, when clicked, pops-up a dialog box for the user to write some information. In the bottom of the dialog box, there are `Save` and `Exit` buttons. When you click `Exit`, the dialog-box closes. If you click the `Insert` button again, the dialog box appears and so on.

The problem is that the dialog box keeps changing its position on the screen every time it's closed and then opened. The horizontal position is the same, however it keeps going down the vertical position couple of inches.

How to fix the position of this dialog-box ?!

Comment: Are you passing a parent window?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld : From my MainWindow.ui, I open the Add_Info.ui form that keeps changing its position everytime it's closed and then re-opened, unless the whole application is closed. If the application re-opened again, then the Add_Info form opens in the original position at the center of the screen. Hope that answer your question (otherwise please explain what do you mean by "passing a parent window")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Placement of windows/dialogs is usually done by your window manager, often applying some kind of (pseudo-)intelligent algorithm. E. g. on KDE you have the choice between several settings, like *Smart*, *Zero-Cornered*, *Random* etc.

To make sure a Qt dialog is always placed at the same position on show you'll have to save and restore the position yourself, using `QWidget::move()` or `QWidget::restoreGeometry()`, usually from a reimplemented `show()` slot. Read the docs for this methods; this can be hairy WRT absolute/relative positions.

Comment: Furthermore, on some platforms modal dialog messages are positioned automatically and you can't change their position at all. OS X is one such platform.

Comment: I tried to use restoreGeometry() but I couldn't figure out how it works, I post another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36860487/2135363)

Comment: @Suda.nese Using `QWidget::move()` with some fixed point you could check whether the behaviour is determined by the window manager, or you have to search your own code for the cause.